# BizTalk WCF-WebHttp Adapter SSL Certificate Props

Tags: ssl, biztalk

What is the difference between Client Cert and Service Cert props in the security tab of WCF-BasicHttp, WCF-WebHttp adatpers based recv and send ports and how they are used by BizTalk for SSL authentication?
The documentations are not that specific.

[How to Configure a WCF-WSHttp Send Port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb245939.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Seems reasonably clear in that article to me

The Client Certificate is the one you hold the private key for and is used for signing your messages so the recipient can verify who you are.

> certificate for authenticating this send port to services

---

The Service Certificate is the public key of the service you are connecting too.  This way it can verify that you are connecting to who you think you are connecting too.

> certificate for authenticating the service to which this send port sends messages

This is not required "The default is an empty string." however it is a security feature that prevents someone successfully being able to spoof the web service and intercepting your payload if they manage to poison the DNS entry.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case i only have one certificate that i have to use as Client Certificate for authenticating myself. Why its must to specify a Service certificate too? where my end point does nt need it either.
btw I m using same cert for Client and Service and its working though.

Comment: You don't have to specify it if you do not need it "The default is an empty string."   It is however a safety feature can implement to stop someone spoofing the web services and intercepting your payload.

Comment: I missed to test it with WCF-BasicHttp adatper, there Service Cert always need a value , its not accepting empty string. Is there a way to force it work w/o it?

Comment: That would depend entirely on the Security mode and Transport client credential type you have selected.  Please post a new question with the details of your port configuration and what you are trying to achieve.  Quite a few of them don't require any certificate at all